# Javascript object conversion and sum values

Tags: javascript

How can i convert this object of arrays and sum values for each one:
in each array i need to sum the values and return a new object.

```
const obj1 = [
  {
    "array1" : [
        {"value" : 30},
        {"value" : 30}
    ],
    "array2" : [
        {"value" : 30},
        {"value" : 20}
    ],
    "array3" : [
        {"value" : 30},
        {"value" : 40}
    ]
}
]
```

to an array like this using Javascript :

```
const obj2 = [
  {
    "key": "array1",
    "value": "60",
  },
  {
    "key": "array2",
    "value": "50",
  },
  {
    "key": "array3",
    "value": "70",
  }
]
```

Thanks

Comment: Please may you share a [mcve] of what you've already tried?

Answer (score 2):

You can map over the entries of each object, summing the values for each array with `Array#reduce`.

```js
const obj1 = [
  {
    "array1" : [
        {"value" : 30},
        {"value" : 30}
    ],
    "array2" : [
        {"value" : 30},
        {"value" : 20}
    ],
    "array3" : [
        {"value" : 30},
        {"value" : 40}
    ]
}
];
let res = obj1.flatMap(x => Object.entries(x).map(([key, v]) => 
            ({key, value: "" + v.reduce((a, b) => a + b.value, 0)})));
console.log(res);
```